# How does pre-allocating a pool of SocketAsyncEventArgs objects upfront improve the performance of a server application in c#

Tags: c#, .net, sockets, memory-management, tcp

In server applications, efficient management of incoming connections is essential for achieving optimal performance. I've come across a common optimization technique used in TCP socket programming, as demonstrated in Microsoft's code samples, which involves pre-creating a pool of SocketAsyncEventArgs objects before the server starts,

[code sample](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.sockets.socketasynceventargs?view=net-8.0)

As shown in the code sample, this approach aims to improve server performance by pre-allocating a fixed number of SocketAsyncEventArgs objects. These objects are then used to handle incoming connections by reusing them without the need for re-creation.
However, I'm struggling to understand how this technique truly enhances performance. Let's consider a scenario where a server is designed to handle a maximum of 10 simultaneous connections,

Before creating the server, a pool of 10 SocketAsyncEventArgs objects is initialized and added to the pool. While this allows for the reuse of objects without constant creation and destruction, it presents limitations. For instance, if the server only has 5 connected clients,
then the remaining 5 SocketAsyncEventArgs objects in the pool are unused, This raises the question: does pre-allocating a fixed pool of objects limit scalability and resource utilization?

if you think about it An alternative approach could involve dynamically creating SocketAsyncEventArgs objects as connections are accepted,
For each new client connection, a new SocketAsyncEventArgs object is instantiated and associated with the client session. This method avoids pre-allocation constraints and optimizes resource usage by only creating objects on demand.,

When considering this, it seems that both methods utilize the same amount of resources to create the SocketAsyncEventArgs objects if the server have a max number of connection,

In the first method, a fixed number of objects is created upfront,
while in the second method, objects are created on demand, Given this, how does pre-allocating a fixed pool of SocketAsyncEventArgs objects enhance performance compared to dynamically creating objects on demand ?

thank you.

just a qu for some methods

Comment: Allocating itself could have a cost, and there is the question of cache locality. But it's arguable either way. An initial amount for typical usage would make sense. 10 small objects is not a lot at all in the grand scheme.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> does pre-allocating a fixed pool of objects limit scalability and resource utilization?

It will at least waste some amount of memory some of the time. If it imposes any practical limit on scalability will depend on the specific implementation and use case. I lack experience to tell if it would be an actual problem in this specific case.

> if you think about it An alternative approach could involve dynamically creating SocketAsyncEventArgs objects as connections are accepted, For each new client connection, a new SocketAsyncEventArgs object is instantiated and associated with the client session. This method avoids pre-allocation constraints and optimizes resource usage by only creating objects on demand.,

You will need to consider if and when objects should be released as connections are closed. Some type of pools decrease in size size slowly as the demand decreases. Others might keep allocated resources forever.

> In the first method, a fixed number of objects is created upfront, while in the second method, objects are created on demand, Given this, how does pre-allocating a fixed pool of SocketAsyncEventArgs objects enhance performance compared to dynamically creating objects on demand ?

Allocating several objects at once can help keep objects sequentially in memory, and that may help with cache usage. It might also be *slightly* faster to allocate several at once rather than one at a time.

But I think the bigger issue is one of complexity and tradeoffs. A fixed size pool is less complex than a dynamic one. And if the fixed one works well enough, why bother spending time to develop, profile and test something more complex? And keep opportunity cost in mind, even if it is worth doing, is it the *best* thing to spend limited resources at? This relates in to the [golden rule of optimization](https://stackify.com/premature-optimization-evil/), only spend your limited resources optimizing the things that actually matter.